# Prompt for 4 options in a loop and option 1 gets input for an array

Tags: c, arrays, input

The question is too long and complicated to put in the title so i'll try to describe it here:

A loop prompts for 4 options (1,2,3,q) and if you enter 1, you input an account # in accounts[MAX] array. If the total index # of accounts is greater than 10 then it no longer accepts input but if accounts[5] and accounts[11] have the same account # (both are 1400) then it continues to accept it. How can I check if the 2 accounts are the same and if they are to allow input to be entered?

my code so far:

```
do
{
    printf ("Options Available: \n");
    printf ("\n 1 - Enter a transaction");
    printf ("\n 2 - View the general journal");
    printf ("\n 3 - View the balance sheet");
    printf ("\n q - Quit the program\n");

    printf ("\nPlease enter 1, 2, 3 or q: ");

    option = validateoption();

    if (option == '1' && totalinput >= MAXtrans)
        printf (" **Maximum number of transactions have been entered\n\n");

    if (option == '1')
    {
        printf ("\nEnter an account number (between 1000 and 3999): ");
        accounts[i] = validateaccount();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter d (debit) or c (credit): ");
        debcred[i] = validatedebcred();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter transaction amount: ");
        amount[i] = validateamount();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("\n");

        i++;
        totalinput++;

    }

    if (option == '2')
        journal(accounts, debcred, amount, &totalinput);

    if (option == '3')
        balancesheet(accounts, debcred, amount, &totalinput);

} while (option != 'q');
```

So in accounts[i] if there are 10 accounts entered then it no longer accepts more accounts but if I enter account # 1400 and account[3] or w.e also has the account # of 1400 then it accepts that input because they are the same account and the total number of accounts is still the same.

My validate account function:

```
long validateaccount() {  // VALIDATE INPUT FOR ACCOUNT # IN TRANSACTION FUNCTION

    int keeptrying = 1, rc;
    long i;
    char after;

    do
    {
        rc = scanf ("%ld%c", &i, &after);

        if (rc == 0)
        {
            printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
            clear();
        }
        else if (after != '\n')
        {
            printf (" **Trailing characters try again: ");
            clear();
        }
        else if (i < 1000 || i > 3999)
        {
            printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
        }
        else
        {
                keeptrying = 0;
        }

    } while (keeptrying == 1);

    return i;

}
```

EDIT: Here is a sample output of what it should show hopefully thats more clear?

Options available:

1 - Enter a transaction
 2 - View the general journal
 3 - View the balance sheet
 q - Quit the program

Please enter 1, 2, 3, or q: 1

Enter an account number (between 1000 and 3999) : 3999

Enter d (debit) or c (credit): d

Enter transaction amount: 10000

Options available:

1 - Enter a transaction
 2 - View the general journal
 3 - View the balance sheet
 q - Quit the program

Please enter 1, 2, 3, or q: 1

Enter an account number (between 1000 and 3999) : 3998
 **Maximum number of accounts has been entered

Options available:

1 - Enter a transaction
 2 - View the general journal
 3 - View the balance sheet
 q - Quit the program

Please enter 1, 2, 3, or q: 1

Enter an account number (between 1000 and 3999) : 3999

Enter d (debit) or c (credit): c

Enter transaction amount: 1000

---

so what happens is 3999 account # is entered first, and then 3998 is entered after but after the 3999 was entered the maximum number of accounts was filled up (10 accounts or accounts[10]) but after 3998 was entered, account # 3999 was entered again and the program accepted that input. If it still isn't clear i'll try and explain more!

Comment: "greater than 10 then it no longer accepts input but if accounts[5] and accounts[11] have the same account # (both are 1400)" Sorry I don't understand, because you can only store one element by array slot.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If this is an assignment please copy the question.

Comment: I edited the original comment to show what the output looks like!if you need me to be more clear just ask and ill try and deliver!

Comment: AlbertoBonsanto what i mean is that accounts[5] and accounts[11] have the VALUE of 1400, does that make sense?

Comment: No only the option is a char, and its a char because it only stores 1,2,3,q. accounts[max] is a long so it holds a number value

Comment: Ok well accounts[max] is a long array and stores a long value. option is a char and separate from accounts because option only prompts which option (1,2,3,q) the user selects

Comment: So do you want to keep a trace of the entered? kind of: amount = |1189|3890|3999|......... ?

Comment: Yes. so amount = |100|200|300|400| right? so amount[0] = 100, amount[1] = 200 etc...and then when it gets to like amount[11] which is 1 more than the limit of 10, it won't accept an input. But if amount[11] is equal to 100, then thats the same as amount[0]. and in that instance it accepts the input!

Answer (score 0):

If `i` represents the number of accounts inputted (note that I don't know if you managed correctly the wrong states), `j` represents the position for the element, thinking that `long int` variables are stored in the array `account`, and I will assume that you want to add an update for the state.

> So in accounts[i] if there are 10 accounts entered then it no longer
>   accepts more accounts but if I enter account # 1400 and account[3] or
>   w.e also has the account # of 1400 then it accepts that input because
>   they are the same account and the total number of accounts is still
>   the same.

```
if ( option == '1' )
{
    long int j;

    /* k represents position */
    int k;

    printf ("\nEnter an account number (between 1000 and 3999): ");

    /* If is the last try and the account is inside the array let's update it. */
    /* Pass by reference k. */
    if( ( i == 10 ) && ( isAccount( validateaccount(), &k ) == 1 ) ){ 
        accounts[ k ] = validateaccount();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter d (debit) or c (credit): ");
        debcred[ k ] = validatedebcred();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter transaction amount: ");
        amount[ k ] = validateamount();
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("\n");

        i++;
    }

    /* Pass by reference k. */
    else if( ( i == 10 ) && ( isAccount( validateaccount(), &k ) == 0 ) ){

        printf (" Your input isn't allowed cause the account is not in the list. \n");

    }

    else{
        accounts[ i ] = validateaccount();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter d (debit) or c (credit): ");
        debcred[ i ] = validatedebcred();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter transaction amount: ");
        amount[ i ] = validateamount();
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("\n");

        i++;
    }
}


/* I will think your array is a global variable, let's use a pass by reference function. */
int isAccount( long int a, int * k )
{
    int result = 0;
    int counter, j;

    for( counter = 0; counter < 11; counter++ ){
        if( accounts[ counter ] == a ){
            * k = counter;
            return 1;
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PD: you can use `structs`It would have been 10x easier.

Comment: Not exactly sure what this is doing? Could you explain what each section does?

Comment: Specifically "if( ( i == 10 ) && ( isAccount( validateaccount(), &k ) == 1 ) ){ "  and "else if( ( i == 10 ) && ( isAccount( validateaccount(), &k ) == 0 ) ){
"  "int isAccount( long int a, int * k )" functions!

Comment: If you will enter a 10 value, and the account you entered is inside the list of accounts ( isAccount( validateaccount(), &k ) ) then you can update the account, in the case that you enter a 10 value and the account is not in the list ignore the input